# Как по простому воспроизвести mp3 в Delphi через BASS

Tags: delphi, аудио, mp3, bass.dll

Нужно простейшее воспроизведение звука - всего 2 функции:

1. Играть
2. Обрубить все играющие звуки

Вот как я делаю - чёт не выходит

Инициализация:

```
  Load_BASSDLL('bass.dll');
  BASS_Init(1, 44100, BASS_DEVICE_3D, MyHandle, nil);
  BASS_Start;
```

Функция:

```
function TQipPlugin.BASS_PlaySoundFile(const FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ChannelInfo: BASS_CHANNELINFO;
begin
  Result:= False;
  Channel:= BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, PChar(FileName), 0, 0, 0);

  if (Channel <> 0) then
  begin
    BASS_ChannelPlay(Channel, False);
  end;
  Result:= Channel <> 0;
end;
```

Использую:

```
  BASS_PlaySoundFile('M:\test.mp3');
```

Использую официальный API: [Delphi dynamic loading API](http://www.un4seen.com/stuff/bass24-delphidyn.zip)

**Результат - не играет =(**
Но выполняется без исключений.
Если есть идеи проще ( не через BASS ) - буду им рад

Comment: Можно исходник побаловаться?
Вот [ссылка](http://www.delphicode.org/multimedia/mp3.htm) если поможет. На работе звука нет проверить не могу, через часика два отпишусь.

Comment: Это плагин к QIP как вы наверно заметили - весь исходник почти и состоит из этих функций ) Могу кинуть если интересно =)